# how to set up github actions for dart and python

Tags: github-actions, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to set up a github actions container with both dart and python. I have used the dart actions template and installed python. However, I keep getting an error saying

```
WARNING: The directory '/github/home/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /__t/Python/3.8.7/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.0.1)
/__w/_temp/95e6ebc6-5365-42a8-8197-9f5d14c042d3.sh: 2: /__w/_temp/95e6ebc6-5365-42a8-8197-9f5d14c042d3.sh: pip: not found
```

Here is my `yaml` file:

```
name: Dart

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Note that this workflow uses the latest stable version of the Dart SDK.
    # Docker images for other release channels - like dev and beta - are also
    # available. See https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart/ for the available
    # images.
    container:
      image:  google/dart:latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
          
      - name: Print Dart SDK version
        run: dart --version

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: | 
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install flake8 pytest
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
          cd integ_tests
          dart pub get

      # Run uvicorn
      - name: Run uvicorn
        run: |
          cd fastapi/
          uvicorn app.main:app --reload --port 8000
          
      # run my test
      - name: Run dart test
        run: |
          cd integ_tests
          dart lib/main.dart --dry true
```

Additionally, I'm concerned that running `uvicorn` inside the container will make the container hang (since it would never exit). If this is the case, how do I go about starting a localhost with uvicorn without letting the container run forever?

EDIT: full log
[image]

If I run it with `sudo` I get an error saying

```
/__w/_temp/2ffb7222-f1dd-4273-870c-c85ac57b9da3.sh: 1: /__w/_temp/2ffb7222-f1dd-4273-870c-c85ac57b9da3.sh: sudo: not found
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full log. Can you provide the URL for the repo with the specific GitHub Action that failed?

Comment: @MoneyBall, is there a particular reason you're upgrading pip in the first step of your dependency installation step?

Comment: @astrochun this is actually my own repo which is private at the moment.

Comment: @jidicula well more often that not pip is not upgraded to the latest version. Additionally, this was the template provided by Github actions.

Comment: I believe the issue stem from not having `pip` install in the docker container. I had a similar issue where I had `git` was not found even though the runner had `git` installed. That is why I asked for the full log to see which step it was failing.

Comment: @astrochun interesting. That could may be the case, however, I don't see anything more in the full log other than what I posted. I uploaded the full log.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here is still that you are attempting to run `pip` inside the container. Here's why. The `dart` version is provided after the `setup-python` but before `pip` installation. I would change the order to ensure that `dart --version` step is before the "Run dart test" step. This will ensure that all python build and configure is done right after `setup-python`

I looked at a Python build of mine and on the step of upgrading pip, I get this:

```
> Run python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages (21.0.1)
Collecting pytest
```

I believe this will have `uvicorn` running outside the container (i.e., in the runner VM).

Comment: Have you tried to build this locally using the `dart` image? This might help to root out the problem.